# How to prevent flash player from creating a mm.cfg file in my home directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash, ubuntu-11.10

Every time I delete the `mm.cfg` file in my `~/` directory, it's automatically generated again later, I'm guessing after some site requests for my browser to load flash. I don't even know how to begin fixing this and would really appreciate some help!

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

Update: it is created when I launch firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Flash Debugger Add-on installed in Firefox, and removed it (if you don't need it of course)

It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2008/08/secrets_of_the_mmscfg_file_1.html) the `mm.cfg` file in your `~` is not harmful in any way.

> mm.cfg: user-local configuration file; lives in user’s home directory on Unix systems and is largely only useful when using content debugger versions of the Player

So I don't see a reason why you would want to delete it. Just leave it alone. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it bugs you that much, you could create a script which launches firefox and then deletes the file, assuming flash doesn't recreate it at some point if it gets deleted.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/firefox &
sleep 3
rm ~/mm.conf
```

Something like that should work. It's not the "prevent a file with this name from getting created in this location" solution that you were likely looking for, but it may serve the purpose.

(You could also try using a different version of flash, as I use Firefox with flash on Linux and it doesn't create that file for me. I don't know what's available on Ubuntu though.)